# How do I start an application on another desktop as default?

Tags: startup-applications

I want to start certain applications like TeamViewer from my startup application, but on a particular desktop everytime.

Is this possible using a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under CompizConfig Settings Manager >> Place Windows >> Fixed Window Placement >> Windows with fixed viewport, configure as follows - class=Wine, x=2, y=1, and that works fine.

To get the correct window name, use the + button and Grab the title.